# Facebook NeuralProphet - Generating model file

Tags: pandas, facebook-prophet, prophet

Trying to understand if I can use pickle for storing the model in a file system.

```
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet
import pandas as pd
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
pipe = NeuralProphet()
pipe.fit(df, freq="D")
pickle.dump(pipe, open('model/pipe_model.pkl', 'wb'))
```

**Question:-** Loading multiple CSV files. I have multiple CSV file. How can i dump multiple CSV files in the same pickle file and load later for the prediction?

Comment: Why don't you use `with open('neuralprophet_model.pkl', "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(m, f)`

Comment: Good suggestion. The code here is just a sample code.

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate these csv files into a file and dump it using pandas?

Comment: @dasmehdix I have last 5 years of data and then will get feed every week with the new data. Do I need to always train with the complete set. What I was thinking is, I need to just add the new file for the training and this will be added to the existing trained model data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right answer here is [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). SQLite acts like a database but it is stored as a single self-contained file on disk.

The benefit for your use case is that you can append new data as received into a table on the file, then read it as required. The code to do this is as simple as:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
# Create a SQL connection to our SQLite database
# This will create the file if not already existing
con = sqlite3.connect("my_table.sqlite")

# Replace this with read_csv
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1, 2, 3], data = [1, 2, 3], columns=['some_data'])

# Simply continue appending onto 'My Table' each time you read a file
df.to_sql(
    name = 'My Table',
    con = con,
    if_exists='append'
)
```

Please be aware that SQLite performance drops after very large numbers of rows, in which case caching the data as `parquet` files or another fast and compressed format, then reading them all in at training time may be more appropriate.

When you need the data, just read everything from the table:

`pd.read_sql('SELECT * from [My Table]', con=con)`